# Is it safe to target the Bot Framework SDK to .NET 5?

Tags: botframework, .net-5

We've recently started a project with the Virtual Assistant Template `1.0.1`, and I wonder if it is safe to target the solution to `net5.0` since we have some libraries that use this latest .NET GA release.

Currently, the VA template references the Bot Framework SDK `4.9.3`. Any requirements on the SDK version?

I've done a couple of tests to confirm. The project compiles, and I can't see any errors. However, I'm looking for some confirmation from the community.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no obvious problems with targeting .NET 5. But if you'd like to be safe, you should go with the version the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/EchoBot.csproj#L4) are using:

```xml
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. Good to see you here. I've opened an issue to track this https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5130